# Can I ignore resistor for IR LED?

Tags: led, resistors, diodes, raspberry-pi, resistance

I have two IR diodes and I want to connect them to my Raspberry Pi. From Pi I have 3.3V voltage. Diodes are [TSAL 6200](http://www.vishay.com/docs/81010/tsal6200.pdf) .

Can I connect them to PNP and my PI without resistor safely with this [wiring](http://mvartan.com/images/remote-pi/bb.png)?

Comment: Depends on your definition of safe

Comment: No. You need some kind of current-limiting, be it a simple ballast resistor, a transistor operating as a linear current sink, or a switching driver.

Comment: Safe I mean not to burn my leds. My lowest resistor is 2,7k. It is nonsense to put it or ?

Comment: You need two resistors here. One on the transistor base and the second in series with the LED. **Both** are needed.

Comment: Why would you not put resistors? They are needed to limit the current anyway.

Comment: Show us normal schematic, not this crappy model.

Comment: [Here's](http://mvartan.com/images/remote-pi/schem.png) an schematic, for the pedantic ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Connecting two diodes in *parallel*:

**No. Don't do this**. The maximum voltage for the LEDs is 3V, and only for 100us pulses. 3.3V will more than likely ruin the diode, although it's unlikely that this will happen in practice. Putting only 3V across a single diode will draw 1A according to the data sheet. I cannot imagine the RaspberryPi will be very happy with this and will probably shut down or just brown out, reducing the 3.3V line down to something that doesn't break the diode, but also doesn't let you use the Pi properly.

Connecting two diodes in *series*:

This will **probably be fine** providing the diodes are not on constantly, and the on/off duty cycle and on-time limits given in the datasheet are observed. However, I don't recommend this. Two diodes in series will have 1.65V across them, putting the current consumption at ~300mA. If you add a normal diode in series you will drop the voltage across each diode to around 1.3, which puts the doide in the realms of 'normal operating conditions'. Asking if the resistor can be omitted suggests you have very few components at your disposal so I understand if you cannot do this, but you must understand the consequences of running components outside of their comfort zones.

Comment: I wouldn't try this as 300mA is still a high current for a GPIO pin of a rasberry pie. You would probably need the GPIO to drive the gate of a nfet to drive higher current to LED, but still the resistor is needed for each LED!

Comment: @lucas92 The OP specifically mentions using a transistor. The linked wiring diagram also includes a transistor. At no point in my answer do I say that a transistor is not needed. It is implicit.

Comment: I decided not to connect without resistor. Thanks for you suggestions and opinion